# Sonarqube VSTS build task building angular/typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, azure-devops

Problem with VSTS Sonarqube task when analysing **none** .NET projects - this is a angular/typescript project. Is this not supported?

I get this error

```
    2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z ##[error]The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z ##[error]Possible causes:
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z ##[error]1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z ##[error]2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 upwards are supported
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z ##[error]3. The begin, build or end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z 15:55:14.781  Creating a summary markdown file...
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8461722Z ##[error]15:55:14.783  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8571628Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8571628Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-09-21T22:55:14.8571628Z    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2017-09-21T22:55:15.3215188Z 
2017-09-21T22:55:15.3215188Z 
2017-09-21T22:55:15.3385192Z Waiting on the SonarQube server to finish processing in order to determine the quality gate status.
2017-09-21T22:55:15.3385192Z 
2017-09-21T22:55:15.3385192Z 
2017-09-21T22:55:15.3544989Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407 ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407
2017-09-21T22:55:15.3544989Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace --
```

Comment: To verify: you have a .NET project with no .NET files in it, only JavaScript/TypeScript?

Comment: How do you create project and how do you build the project?

Comment: Sorry missed answer - i got a pure typescript angular project without .NET at all. I wanna check typescript errors and html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SonarQube Scanner CLI task to analysis node.js project.

A blog: [SonarSource have announced their own SonarQube Team Services / TFS integration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/12/13/sonarsource-have-announced-their-own-sonarqube-team-services-tfs-integration/)